# git-push tag sending too many objects

Tags: git, git-push

I'm facing an issue when pushing new tags to the remote repository. It seems to be sending the whole repository for every new tag. However, I create the tags from the branch I work on, pushing the branch before I push the tag. When I push the branch, it just sends the new commit objects.

I have been using the following procedure for over 2 years without problems, until recently.

I make some changes in local development branch (e.g. master) and then push it to remote:

```
host:folder user$ git push origin master
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
updating 'refs/heads/master'
  from 226334abbe733ffa8bb1a0fb8a34843aa9127c13
  to   ccdfb7de73d4a17b31aa83e0c9626e19b23717ac
    sending 23 objects
    done
Updating remote server info
To https://githost/repo/
   226334a..ccdfb7d  master -> master
```

Then I checkout the production branch, merge the changes and push that branch, too:

```
host:folder user$ git checkout production
Switched to branch 'production'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/production'.

host:folder user$ git merge master
Updating 226334a..ccdfb7d
Fast-forward
 CHANGELOG.txt                                                   |  8 ++++++++
 data/migrations/Version20160704122217.php                       | 30 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 module/FileStorage/src/FileStorage/Entity/Node.php              |  3 ++-
 module/FileStorage/src/FileStorage/Entity/Node/Impression.php   |  2 +-
 .../view/file-storage/partials/bucket/_history.phtml            |  2 +-
 5 files changed, 42 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)

host:folder user$ git push origin production
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
updating 'refs/heads/production'
  from 226334abbe733ffa8bb1a0fb8a34843aa9127c13
  to   ab9069e85d1557129b1fb3cd4cd97e9708316133
    sending 26 objects
    done
Updating remote server info
To https://githost/repo/
   226334a..ab9069e  production -> production
```

So far, so good. 
Then I create a new tag and push that. This is when it sends too many objects:

```
host:folder user$ git tag -a 1.3.21 -m "deploy 1.3.21"
host:folder user$ git push origin 1.3.21
Fetching remote heads...
  refs/
  refs/heads/
  refs/tags/
updating 'refs/tags/1.3.21'
  from 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
  to   98008ee504cd2997bb8a160e497bc82d2c539a0e
    sending 46340 objects
    done
Updating remote server info
To https://githost/repo/
 * [new tag]         1.3.21 -> 1.3.21
```

I have made sure that my local branches are up to date. When I do

```
host:folder user$ git fetch origin
host:folder user$ git rev-list origin/master..master
host:folder user$ git rev-list origin/production..production
```

I get no results, which I interpret as there are no missing commits in the local branches.

I have read a lot of related posts here, but have not found an answer or a poster having the exact same issue.

Any hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

**EDIT**: Some info about my git version and settings (anonymised):

```
host:folder user$ git version
git version 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66)

host:folder user$ git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=John Doe
user.email=john@example.org
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://githost/folder
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.production.remote=origin
branch.production.merge=refs/heads/production
```

Comment: Weird, when I do a push, I don't get any of the "Fetching remote heads..." output. I'm on  git 2.7.4 (Apple Git-66) and creating a new tag for me and pushing it doesnt send all those objects either. What version of git are you using?

Comment: Also, what are your config flags? (git config --list)

Comment: @DavidN I added the config settings in the question, thx :)

Comment: What do you think the number 46340 represents? Is it closer to the count of files in your project at this point in time or to the count of objects in the history of the `production` branch (i.e. each file being counted as many times as it has revisions on that branch)?

Comment: @Leon I think it is the count of commit objects. The number is increasing by the number of new commit objects since the last tag. E.g. if I make a change with 15 new objects in the branch and then create and push a new tag, the count will have gone up by 15. Also, files are less than a third of that number.